# Increase the number of 'Most used' applications in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

How can I increase the number of applications which are displayed under 'Most used' from the default 6 apps?

Comment: I don't know if this regedit value is still present in *Windows 10*, but you can try setting [`Start_MinMFU`](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Start_MinMFU) value to `6` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` (I'm Linux-oriented and I can't check if it works because I don't have *Windows 10*).

Comment: BTW: Your question [reminds me](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/yandros/doc/gui-considered-harmful) nice quote: _GUIs make simple things simple, and complex ones impossible_.

Comment: The registry key does not work.

Comment: I avoid Windows personally and don't have Windows 10 to check but take a look at the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced for the Start_TrackProgs Dword. I'm not sure if it's a numeric value that you can change. You might find this of interest: http://www.askvg.com/collection-of-windows-10-hidden-secret-registry-tweaks/

Comment: I landed here seeking how to *shorten* the Most Used List. That's because I made keyboard shortcuts for all my most frequently used apps. It's not the answer you were looking for, but perhaps it's an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that it is not possible as of right now to add more items to the Most Used apps.
What you can do is go into settings > personalization > start
There you can choose what is shown on the start menu, but the only things you can add that are not there already are folders.

You can use something called classic shell to personalize the start menu 
http://www.infoworld.com/article/2972763/microsoft-windows/windows-10-start-menus-start10-vs-classic-shell.html

Comment: Love it how if the answer is not what the asker wants to hear it just gets downvoted...

Comment: Came across your answer & noticed the downvotes & your comment.  Saying something isn't possible can be the right answer, but that, alone, leaves a question of whether you're correct or just don't know the solution.  This kind of answer is always better if you can cite a source.  The solution you added is just a link.  External links can break, in which case the "solution" would have no value.  For this reason, we ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Link-only answers attract downvotes.  Anyway, welcome to SU.

Comment: @rzfzr - I almost always find answers which only contain links not to be helpful.  Since you claim it "is not possible", without any sort of supporting documentation from Microsoft, I find it hard to find this answer helpful.

Answer (score 4):

No such control is currently available; please open the Windows Feedback app in Windows 10 and upvote the suggestions there to add this. There are several suggestions for this already, so no need to add one. The suggestions to increase the number are actually trending as of right now (April 2016).

In the app, navigate to the 'Start and action centre' section and search for 'increase the number of most used apps'. Open Click the 'Upvote' button under the suggestions to add your vote.

Edit: I would gladly add this as a comment, if I had the ability to comment.

Comment: We already have this as [an answer for this question](http://superuser.com/a/961000/45163). The data you provided would help as a comment.

Comment: I would love to, but alas, I don't have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Go into start and move the cursor to the top of the menu. Drag up from the top to increase size and the opposite to decrease size. Size= Number of items.

Comment: Well, no. The situation is rather ridiculous specifically because we can change the vertical size of the start menu (as you described), but it has no effect on the number of most used programs listed on the left-hand side. It remains at 6.

Answer (score -2):

This has basically been around since XP/7.

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b90047/ebook/winXPhack/0596005113_winxphks-chp-2-sect-5.html

Quote:

> By default, the Most Frequently Used Programs List has room for six programs, but you can change that default and have more or fewer programs appear. Right-click on the Start button and choose Properties Customize General. The Customize Start Menu dialog box appears. To customize the number of programs to include on the list, edit the "Number of programs on Start menu" box. You can choose any number between 0 and 30. Be aware, though, that depending on your screen resolution and whether you're using large or small icons, the entire list might not appear if you choose a large number. No matter how high your resolution is, for example, don't expect there to be room for 30 programs.