# Most used items in Windows 10 start menu limited to 6

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

How do I make the start menu contain more than the 6 mostly used apps? When I remove one from the list, another is ready to appear, so there is some limit, but I cant find the setting?

Comment: As of today, I think it's not possible. Here is a bigger threat about the same issue: http://superuser.com/questions/949563/increase-the-number-of-most-used-applications-in-windows-10